# youtube and primevideo full screen issue with windows power setting

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, youtube

I am using firefox developer edition 72.0b6 (64-bit) and window 10 operating system.

Let me explain the configuration and issue.

I have set my window power setting "Turn of the display" to "1 minute".

So if i am watching youtube or primevideo video in full screen and then pause the video for more the 1min. As per the power setting, the display will turn off.

Now here some the issue, when i resume the video. Display will turn on, video and audio will resume but with dark grey screen.

To reset the video screen i have to escape from full screen.

Having same issue in chrome.

Please help with this issue and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

- [Reset Firefox add-ons](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings)
- If the above won't work then you can go ahead and reinstall Firefox.